# AWS CloudWatch Log on Android

Tags: android, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to use AWS CloudWatch Log in an Android app.
I have the following config for the aws-client:

```
val basicAWSCredentials = BasicAWSCredentials(
        “Xxxxxx”,
        “Yyyyyy”
)
val awsLogsClientBuilder = AWSLogsClientBuilder.standard()
awsLogsClientBuilder.region = Regions.EU_WEST_2.name
awsLogsClientBuilder.credentials = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials)
awsClient = awsLogsClientBuilder.build()
```

In the build.gradle I have

```
implementation ("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-logs:1.11.367") {
    exclude module: 'joda-time'
}
```

The app is crashing at `awsLogsClientBuilder.build()` with the following exception:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.xxxxxx.xxxxx, PID: 28703
>       java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)...

I have tried to use the android specific library as well:

```
androidSdkLogsVersion = "2.6.24"
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-logs:$androidSdkLogsVersion"
```

and/or

```
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:$androidSdkLogsVersion"
```

but if I use it along with the java sdk I get an error at compile time:

> Program type already present: com.amazonaws.ResponseMetadata

If I do not import the java-sdk then I get an error at compile time because the class `AWSLogsClientBuilder` is not found anymore.

How should I create the logger on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did:

In the build.gradle

```
androidSdkLogsVersion = "2.6.24"
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-logs:$androidSdkLogsVersion"
```

and to configure the logger:

```
val basicAWSCredentials = BasicAWSCredentials("xxxxx","yyyy")
val awsClient = AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient(basicAWSCredentials)
val regions: Regions = Regions.EU_WEST_1
awsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(regions.getName()))
```

Comment: Is there a wrapper or library to handle this job

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the AWS Java SDK ***V2***. It will allow you to use an alternate HTTP runtime, and avoid some of the mess with the Apache client, when working on Android.

[GitHub Issue #1180](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1180) in the AWS Java SDK V2 repo addresses this topic.

In your module-level `build.gradle`, add dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:cloudwatch:2.13.49'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client:2.13.49'
}
```

Now, initialize the CloudWatch client:

```kotlin
val cloudwatch = CloudWatchClient.builder()
    .httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.create())
    .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
    .credentialsProvider(yourCredentialsHere())
    .build()
```

Comment: @ParagPawar You can use `CloudWatchLogsClient` instead of `CloudWatchClient`. Please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html and https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cloudwatchlogs/CloudWatchLogsClient.html#putLogEvents-software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.model.PutLogEventsRequest-

Comment: thanks, I used AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient which works fine with aws-android-sdk-logs